# Is it safe to use a dummy fake lock with std::condition_variable_any?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

What I am looking for is something like the wait_queue_t in linux kernel.  My underlying data structure related to the synchronization is lockfree thus does not need protection of a mutex.

Having to acquire `std::mutex` just to be able to use `std::condition_variable` for blocking wait seems to introduce unnecessary overhead.

I know there is `futex` for linux and `WaitOnAddress` for Windows but I am more interested in language standard stuff here.

According to [cppreference wiki](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any) `std::condition_variable_any` can work with any custom `Lockable`.

So what if I use it with a dummy fake lock like the following:

```
class FakeLock
{
public:
    inline void lock() {}
    inline void unlock() {}
    inline bool try_lock() { return true; }
};

template<typename WaitLock=FakeLock>
class WaitQueue
{
private:
    WaitLock m_lock;
    std::condition_variable_any m_cond;

public:
    inline void wait()
    {   
        std::unique_lock<WaitLock> lock(m_lock);

        m_cond.wait(lock);
    }   

    inline void notify_one()
    {   
        m_cond.notify_one();
    }   

    inline void notify_all()
    {   
        m_cond.notify_all();
    }   
};
```

Is there any potential risk of unexpected behavior to use the `WaitQueue` above in the way linux kernel `wait_queue_t` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about the problem again I think I got an answer.

Given a class `LockFreeStack` which is a lockfree stack.

consider the following code:

```
WaitQueue wq;
LockFreeStack<std::string> stack;

std::thread t1([&]() {
    while (true) {
         // sleep for some time
         stack.push(/* random string */);          // (1.1)
         wq.notify_one();                          // (1.2)
    }
});

std::thread t2([&]() {
    while (true) {
         if (stack.empty())                        // (2.1)
             wq.wait();                            // (2.2)
         auto str = stack.pop();
         // print string
    }
});
```

Without guarding wait_queue / conditional variable with a real lock, it is possible for the two threads to execute in the following sequence:

```
(2.1)
(1.1)
(1.2)
(2.2)
```

Making thread `t2` perfectly miss the latest update from `t1`. `t2` will only be able to resume execution after the next `notify_one()` call.

A real lock is necessary to guarantee that the conditional variable is changed atomically with the actual data/state of interest.

Comment: `if (stack.empty()) wq.wait();` should be atomic